# Can I Integrate Zapier in my Website With all its Capabilities?

Tags: api, zapier

I have a Usecase in which i need to integrate all the capabilities of **zapier**,like zap creation ,creation of a workflow etc via my  website (not an app)  which is not related to **zapier** in any ways.

In short i need to give my Website Users ,all privileges that zapier provides.
Is that possible ?

if yes ,Please help me with the **api's** available for such an integration.Looking forward for a help.

Answer (score 4):

Zapier does not have an API or whitelabel option that would allow for this - Zaps can only be created via zapier.com. The only exception is the Partner API, which allows Zapier integrations to embed and display their own Zap Templates - details on that here: https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/partner-api/. That's only accessible if you've built an app on Zapier's platform.